# Find matching value in nested list from list

Tags: python, csv

I read two .csv files like this.

```
ori = "all.csv"
det = "find.csv"

names = []
namesa = []


with open(det, "r") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        cells = row.split(",")
        if len(cells) > 2:
            b = cells[1]
            c = b.split("-")
            names.append(c[0])


with open(ori, "r") as rcursor1: #read the document
    for trow in rcursor1: #read each row
        row1 = trow.split(",") #split it by your seperator
        namesa.append(row1)
```

Works just fine.
`namesa` is a nested list where every row from my .csv is a list (see example) while `names`contains the values which I want to find in `namesa`. 
If the value from `names` is in `namesa`, I want the whole "nested list part". So i.e.

```
#example
namesa = [[a,b,c,], [a1, b1, c1], [xy, cd, e2], [u1, i1, il], ...]
names = [a, u1,]
return = [[a1, b1, c1], [u1, i1, il], ...] 

#or
namesa = [[john,bill,catherina,], [marti, alex, christoph], [ben, sherlock, london], [Bern, paris, Zürich], ...]
names = [sherlock, marti]
results = [[marti, alex, christoph],  [ben, sherlock, london]]
```

Well, that does not work.
Thats what I tried so far:

```
#did not return any match
d = list([b for b in namesa if b in [a for a in names]])
print d


#did not return any match neither
for a in namesa:
    for b in names:
        if b in a:
            print "match"


#well, that did not work neither
for a in namesa:
    for b in names:
        if a[5] == b:
            print "match"
```

There are no matches coming back. I opened my two csv files in excel and searched "by hand" for matches which returned me results...
What am I doing wrong here? Working with python.

Comment: do you have some examples of the data in the csv files.

Comment: In your example I don't understand why `[a1, b1, c1]` is part of your resulting list `return` instead of `[a,b,c]` because it's `a` in `names` and *not* `a1`?

Comment: @halex `names` is my list with the search word and I want every list (of my nested list `namesa`) returned which contains whatever is in `names`

Comment: @Stophface Ok, but your first list in `return` has none of your `names` values.

Comment: @halex I dont understand. `namesa` contains `a` and `u1` which is in `names`

Comment: @Stophface `namesa` consists of lists that contain some strings, so `a` or `u1` are not directly part of `namesa` but part of the sublists. I thought you want all sublists that contain at least one part of `names`? Your resulting list `return` contains `[a1, b1, c1]` but neither `a1`nor `b1` nor `c1` are part of `names`

Comment: @halex, you are totally right. Since I am comparing names it would be nice if the names match exactly and do not just contain a single letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use .csv file I'd suggest you to use csv module.
I'd to this this way (I'm assuming that things you're looking for are in column 'surname'. If they are in different columns you can consider iterating by them, or doing `name in row['surname'] or name in row['name']`, depends on complication:

```
import csv
result = []
listFromCSV = []
names = ['alex','sherlock']
csvFile = open('yourFile.csv')
reader = csv.DictReader(csvFile)
fieldnames = reader.fieldnames
for row in reader:
    listFromCSV.append(row)
csvFile.close()
for name in names:
    for row in listFromCSV:
        if name.strip() in row['surname']:
            result.append(row)
```

And if you want to get rid of duplicates append `break` at the end of last for loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
namesa = [['john', 'bill', 'catherina'], ['cat', 'dog', 'foo'], ['noodle', 'bob']]
names = ['john','foo']
```

Try this

```
for n in names:
    for arr in namesa:
        if n.strip() in ''.join(arr):
            print arr
```

`.strip` because the values in your `names` list seem to have trailing spaces.

Comment: Can you post the actual contents of both lists?

Comment: If there are matches this will work. See the example lists in my answer. Do they match yours?

Comment: My lists are like `namesa = [[john,bill,catherina,], [marti, alex, christoph], [ben, sherlock, london], [Bern, paris, Zürich], ...]` and 
`names = [sherlock, marti,]`
My result must be `results = [[marti, alex, christoph],  [ben, sherlock, london], ]` sine `marti` and ` sherlock` occur in the nested lists.

Comment: Check my updated answer. One issue is that it leads to duplicates.

Comment: Thats works, sort off. I get results now, but that are not all my results. It returns ~20 while it should return ~150

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73240/discussion-between-kedar-and-stophface).

Answer (score 0):

```
namesa = [['john','bill','catherina',], ['marti', 'alex', 'christoph'], ['ben', 'sherlock', 'london']]

names = ['sherlock', 'marti']

for i in namesa:
  for j in names:
    if j in i:
        print i
```

OUTPUT

['marti', 'alex', 'christoph']
['ben', 'sherlock', 'london']